# SQL database optimisation for fast filtering

Tags: database, search

SO, look what I have.

Short text messages, stored in a database as plain text, tagged text and html. For tagged text, tags are embedded into each message. For example, I can have the following tagged message:

```
A [quick] [brown] fox jumps over a [lazy] dog.
```

Quick, Brown and Lazy - are embedded tags, shown in **bold** style in html. Any user can mark another tag, for example [dog]. This happened, I need to refresh *all* messages in the database with a word **dog** and make it a tag **everywhere**.

There are thousands of messages, so I need to filter necessary ones and update them (or insert new values), leave alone that users may change tags concurrently (and also remove them). I'm thinking of a auxiliary table for these needs, to keep something like search index and find messages to be updated fast. Of course, all changed are applied after approval of several other users, just for keeping an order.

Are there any soultions to make the search and update processes more effective or maybe I should choose something else here?

I use Ruby+MySQL if it matters.

Answer (score 0):

If you absolutely must update each message, then you have no real choice other than to brute force change them.  If there are only a few thousand, then it will be quick enough.  However, if it grows to millions, then the time to locate the tags in each message may start to impact unless you use query optimisations and/or play games using background update threads, as you alluded.  (Or change to a temporal database with log support)

If the number of tags is small enough, why not simply maintain a list of tags in a table and when retrieving each message pass each potential tag through the tag table
(ie.  for each word in message, check if word is in tag table).  This will be reasonably quick if messages are short,and tag table can be optimally indexed to help.

One advantage of a tag table is that you can create a message-tag 1:M table to act as a reverse index, which will speed query search, although your question didnt seem to be about search performance.